# Remove duplicate documents using ravendb and .net client

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I have created an index using map reduce to find the duplicates and I am successful in finding the duplicates. Here is my class

```
class Employee {
public string Name {get; set;}
public string address {get; set;}
public string email {get; set;}
}
```

using map reduce , my result is as such

Sal   abc  salo@yahoo.co  2

Here , the data suggests that there are 2 duplicate documents. Now my question is I have to remove one of the documents. Obviously with this way I am not able to get the document id, since I cant do group by on document ID. So what should I do after I have found the duplicates in order to remove one of the documents ?

Here is the code for map reduce

```
namespace DuplicateEmployee.Storage.Indexes
{

    public class DupEmployeeIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Employee, DupEmployeeIndex.UniqueEmployeeResult>
    {

        public class UniqueEmployeeResult
        {
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            public string address1 { get; set; }

            public string address2 { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
            public string state { get; set; }

            public string zip { get; set; }



            public string DOB { get; set; }
            public int Count { get; set; }
        }
        public DupEmployeeIndex()
        {
            Map = employees => from employee in employees
                              select
                               new
                               {
                                  LastName = employee.LastName,
                                  FirstName = employee.FirstName,
                                  address1 = employee.Address1,
                                  address2 = employee.Address2,
                                  city = employee.City,
                                  state = employee.State,
                                  zip = employee.Zip,
                                  DOB = employee.DateOfBirth,
                                  Count = 1
                               };

            Reduce = results => from result in results                         
                                group result by new { result.LastName,
                                    result.FirstName,
                                    result.address1,
                                    result.address2,
                                    result.city,
                                    result.state,
                                    result.zip,
                                    result.DOB

                                   }
                                    into g   

                                select new

                                {

                                    LastName = g.Key.LastName,

                                   FirstName = g.Key.FirstName,
                                  address1 = g.Key.address1,
                                  address2 = g.Key.address2,
                                  city = g.Key.city,
                                  state = g.Key.state,
                                  zip = g.Key.zip,
                                  DOB = g.Key.DOB,
                                    Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)

                                };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for your index.  (Hint: you should be able to use `.First()` in the reduce)

Comment: I just edited the post and I have added the code for the index